# mvn always throwing error "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". nothing helps

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run my project locally it works but the same project in Jenkins throwing me an error.

**SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".**

no matter which maven command I run I get the same error

Comment: No information about where this happens ? In your tests? Which Java version? Which Maven version? How does your pom file look like? I simply don't know...

Comment: java version : 1.8 Maven version 3.5.2

Comment: @khmarbaise this error comes with all the maven commands in Jenkins server.

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J is just an abstraction and you've to provide the implementation of the same by adding the proper binding in your project. By adding one of the following dependency slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: The same project and pom is working in my local. I've issue with running the project in jenkins server.

Comment: Then I guess you need to provide more details. Share the dependency pom etc

Comment: <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: By adding one of the following dependency slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.  How to add this in classpath as far as I know it should get downloaded from pom.

Comment: If you need logging at run time you need to remove this stmt  `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: if I remove the scope then also it doesn't work